# NAT64 configuration with tayga on Debian 6

Tags: linux, networking, debian, nat, ipv6

I'm trying to implement NAT64 with tayga on my server and came to a point where I'm not sure how to proceed.

My server is connected via one IPv4 address and one /64 IPv6 address block to the internet.
It servers all kind of stuff. For reasons I'm also running some LinuX Containers (LXC). These are IPv6 exclusive. I implemented a bridge (br0) on my host system and switched addresses from eth0 to br0. My containers successfully communicate with each other on IPv6. Via mod_proxy on my host I could connect my ipv6 only webservers (LXC) to the IPv4 internet, too. But just in one direction, you could say.

For some auto-update functionalities I need NAT64+DNS6, because some update servers don't speak IPv6.

Let's assume the following and beware that the IP addresses are not really in use.

Host br0:

```
inet address: 10.0.0.1 # external IP
inet6 address: 2a01::1/64 # external IP
```

LXC eth0:

```
# external IP, some ip6tables forward rules implemented on the host 
inet6 address: 2a01::2/64
```

I installed tayga on my host and configured it like that:

```
tun-device nat64
ipv4-addr 192.168.255.1
prefix 2a01:0:0:0:64::/96
map 192.168.255.2 2a01::2
```

Tayga auto chooses an IPv6 address from that /96 subnet.
Then I created the interface.

```
$>tayga --mktun
```

Now, you ought to add each an IPv4 and IPv6 address to the nat64 interface. According to the FAQ it's not a good idea to use the same IP addresses to host uses. On the other hand it's stated to use the routers (internal) addresses. But I could take totally different ones, too, and then would be asked to add the needed routes. Let me cite something:

```
# ip link set nat64 up
# ip addr add 192.168.0.1 dev nat64      (replace with your router's IPv4 address)
# ip addr add 2001:db8:1::1 dev nat64    (replace with your router's IPv6 address)
# ip route add 192.168.255.0/24 dev nat64
# ip route add 2001:db8:1:ffff::/96 dev nat64
```

I'm not sure what to do. What addresses should I use? Just use some private IPv4/IPv6 addresses? And what else is needed?
One source talks about adding some forward rules (I already changed eth0 to br0, as I use br0):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o nat64 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i nat64 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
```

Thing is, I tried thing's and once I could

```
ping6 2a01:0:0:0:64::192.168.255.1
```

on my host. But I couldn't manage to get my LXC talk to any system. Not 2a01:0:0:0:64::192.168.255.1 or maybe 2a01:0:0:0:64::8.8.8.8 (Google).

Right now I don't care about the not yet fully implemented DNS64. I installed some debian package and (think to) know how to configure it, just didn't try it yet.

The sources I consulted:
http://www.litech.org/tayga/
http://www.litech.org/tayga/faq.html
http://www.litech.org/tayga/README-0.9.2
http://ipvsix.me/?p=106
http://stuartl.longlandclan.yi.org/blog/2011/06/23/nat64dns64-in-gentoo/
http://blog.raorn.name/2012/02/ipv6-only-lan-with-dual-stack-openwrt.html

**Update 1:**

```
From 2a01::64:0:c0a8:ff01 icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Unknown code 5
```

That's the address tayga choose on its own. I tried pinging From 2a01:0:0:0:64::8.8.8.8.
I added those mentioned iptables rules and did this:

```
ip link set nat64 up
ip addr add 192.168.255.1 dev nat64
ip addr add 2a01::1 dev nat64
ip route add 192.168.255.0/24 dev nat64
ip route add 2a01:0.0.0.64::/96 dev nat64
```

Still, I can ping 2a01:0:0:0:64::192.168.255.1, but only from my host. My LXC can't even reach that address.

Yes, I ruled out wrong ip6tables rules.